# Structuring a Gdata Spreadsheet query

Tags: php, gdata, google-docs-api, gdata-api, google-sheets

I am trying to build a Zend_Gdata_Spreadsheets_ListQuery and I can't find any references that explain what the expected query syntax is and what types of queries you can and cannot perform. The closest I have been able to come to finding anything is the [Google Data APIs Client Library (1.41.1)] (https://developers.google.com/gdata/javadoc/com/google/gdata/client/spreadsheet/ListQuery#ListQuery(java.net.URL)), which describes the function setSpreadsheetQuery as follows:

> setSpreadsheetQuery
>
> public void setSpreadsheetQuery(java.lang.String query) Sets the
>   structured spreadsheet query. Parameters: query - the query such as
>   "name = 'Sonja' and state = 'Georgia'"

This works just fine if you are looking for a cell whose column title is "name" and that contains the text "Sonja"—and nothing else. I am looking for cells containing "Sonja" as part, of the cell's text. A cell in the "name" column with the value "Sonja the Awesome" for example, would not match the search above. name=Sonya* causes an error and name="Sonya*" returns no results.

So, does anybody know where I can find a rundown of what the expected "structure" for the "structured spreadsheet query" is?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using regex ? Also, make sure to escape the regex special characters.
Something like \bSonja\b